# Show 'MessageBox' at center of RadPane

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, raddocking

I have several **RadPanes** and **RadPanGroups** in my **WPF** application built using **Telerik** controls.

I want to show a **custom window** (kind of message box) that is center to a particular **RadPane** not center to whole window or parent window or screen.

I want to set **Top** and **Left** of **custom window** according to activated **RadPane**

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your question.  http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little workaround, but [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19768952/what-is-the-best-way-to-show-a-wpf-window-at-the-mouse-location-to-the-top-left) might help you. The idea is, to capture mouse position, while firing an event. You didn't say what causes your window to open, I assume it is MouseDoubleClickEvent, so this might suit you.

Another option (haven't tried it) is to capture **sender** parameters within your event. After firing an event, you have sender (which is object, in your case RadPane), which returns VisualOffset of a component (which has 4 coordinates). Then you can manually set your window position as follows:

```
Window window = new Window();
window.Left = offsetTop - x;
window.Top = offsetLeft - y;
```

Unfortunately, WindowStartupLocation property, allows you to set it only to CenterOwner (center of parent window), CenterScreen and Manual. And well, Manual sounds really good, but it still requires you to know exact position of sender (parent).