# How to set the location of WPF window to the bottom right corner of desktop?

Tags: wpf, window, location

I want to show my window on top of the `TaskBar`'s clock when the windows starts.

How can I find the bottom right corner location of my desktop?

I use this code that works well in windows forms app but does not work correctly in WPF:

```
var desktopWorkingArea = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
this.Left = desktopWorkingArea.Right - this.Width;
this.Top = desktopWorkingArea.Bottom - this.Height;
```

Answer (score 135, accepted):

This code works for me in WPF both with Display 100% and 125%

```
 private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    var desktopWorkingArea = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea;
    this.Left = desktopWorkingArea.Right - this.Width;
    this.Top = desktopWorkingArea.Bottom - this.Height;
 }
```

In brief I use

`System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea`

instead of

`System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea`

Comment: Works perfect in Win7.

Comment: Thanks works for me. I add this comment for rookies with WPF like me: `public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Window_Loaded);
        }` that is the way to call it.

Answer (score 11):

To access the desktop rectangle, you could use the [Screen class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.aspx) - `Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea` property is the rectangle of your desktop.

Your WPF window has `Top` and `Left` properties as well as `Width` and `Height`, so you could set those properties relative to the desktop location.

Comment: this works well in windows forms app but doesn't work correctly in my WPF app(the window get out of desktop), where is my mistake?(i edited my question)

Comment: I just created sample WPF application with the code you've posted in your edit and it works perfect for me (on WIN7).

Comment: i found why this happen, in _Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display_ i set my display to 125% if i change this to 100% this code will be correct in WPF also, but how can i do this in WPF without changing my display?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the window's `SizeChanged` event instead of `Loaded` if you want the window to **stay** in the corner when its size changes. This is especially handy if the window has `Window.SizeToContent` set to some value other than `SizeToContent.Manual`; in this case it will adjust to fit the content while staying in the corner.

```
public MyWindow()
{
    SizeChanged += (o, e) =>
    {
        var r = SystemParameters.WorkArea;
        Left = r.Right - ActualWidth;
        Top = r.Bottom - ActualHeight;
    };
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Note also that you should subtract `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` (instead of `Width` and `Height` as shown in some other replies) to handle more possible situations, for example switching between `SizeToContent` modes at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

My code:

```
MainWindow.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;

MainWindow.Loaded += (s, a) =>
{
    MainWindow.Height = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height;
    MainWindow.Width = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width;
    MainWindow.SetLeft(SystemParameters.WorkArea.Location.X);
    MainWindow.SetTop(SystemParameters.WorkArea.Location.Y);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This above solutions did not entirely work for my window - it was too low and the bottom part of the window was beneath the taskbar and below the desktop workspace. I needed to set the position after the window content had been rendered:

```
private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var desktopWorkingArea = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea;
    this.Left = desktopWorkingArea.Right - this.Width - 5;
    this.Top = desktopWorkingArea.Bottom - this.Height - 5;
}
```

Also, part of the frame was out of view, so I had to adjust by 5. Not sure why this is needed in my situation.

Comment: I had a similar issue. Top is fine, but not Left, Right, Width or height of my two windows that I wanted to place side-by-side.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with a new window containing a label named MessageDisplay. The code accompanying the window was as follows:

```
public partial class StatusWindow : Window
{
    static StatusWindow display;

    public StatusWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    static public void DisplayMessage( Window parent, string message )
    {
        if ( display != null )
            ClearMessage();
        display = new StatusWindow();
        display.Top = parent.Top + 100;
        display.Left = parent.Left + 10;
        display.MessageDisplay.Content = message;
        display.Show();
    }

    static public void ClearMessage()
    {
        display.Close();
        display = null;
    }
}
```

For my application, the setting of top and left puts this window below the menu on the main window (passed to DisplayMessage in the first parameter);

Answer (score 0):

@Klaus78 's answer is correct. But since this is first thing google pops up and if working in environments where screen resolution can change often such that your app runs on virtual desktops or virtual servers and you still need it to update its placement when the screen resolution changes I have found linking to the SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged event to be beneficial. Here is an example using rx and you can put this in your constructor for your view.

```
        Observable
            .FromEventPattern<EventHandler, EventArgs>(_ => SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged += _, _ => SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged -= _)
            .Select(_ => SystemParameters.WorkArea)
            .Do(_ =>
            {
                Left = _.Right - Width;
                Top = _.Bottom - Height;
            })
            .Subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, I'm very late with my reply, but it may come in handy if anyone else happens to be passing by.

You can also leave the position calculation to WPF by adding this attribute to the XAML Window tag:

```
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
```

Then all that's missing is 2 lines of code in the Loaded event:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Top *= 2;
    this.Left *= 2;
    //this.Top -= 10; // Optional for margin
    //this.Left -= 10; // Optional for margin
}
```