# Position window at bottom-right corner of the screen

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a C# WPF application, and I need to display its window at the bottom-right corner of screen. How can I do that?

Comment: Did you tried _anything_?

Comment: I have found two parameter in MSDN - `Top` and `Left`, but it dont works for me

Answer (score 2):

In the Window element, set the WindowStartupLocation to equal "Manual" and then set the Height, Width, Left and Top values accordingly.

Comment: That i know. But how i can set position to bottom-right through `Top` and `Left` attributes?

Comment: have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620488/how-to-set-the-location-of-wpf-window-to-the-bottom-right-corner-of-desktop