# Setting Window in WPF to the bottom right

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to set my window to the bottom left.
The window has no title bar and the `height` is set to `auto` and `SizeToContent` is `Height` and `WindowStartupLocation` is `Manual`

After setting the content I am executing these two lines of code:

```cs
Left = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width - Width - 2; 
Top = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height - Height - 2;
```

These two lines are in the SetupWindow() function

```cs
InitializeComponent();            

            foreach (Caller c in callers)
            {
                CallerLine callerline = new CallerLine();
                Hyperlink link = (Hyperlink)callerline.FindName("link");
                ContentControl ccname = (ContentControl)callerline.FindName("ccname");
                ContentControl ccnumber = (ContentControl)callerline.FindName("ccnumber");                

                link.RequestNavigate += hyperlink_RequestNavigate;
                ccname.Content = c.Name;
                ccnumber.Content = " " + c.PhoneNumber;

                spCallers.Children.Add(callerline);
            }

            SetupWindow();
```

I am doing all my setup stuff before I am setting the window to its new position!

Now the window is set somewhere on the Right site of the screen but not on the bottom. How can I set it to the bottom Right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the location of WPF window to the bottom right corner of desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620488/how-to-set-the-location-of-wpf-window-to-the-bottom-right-corner-of-desktop)

Comment: no, as you can see I am doing the same as the answer in the post is, but it does not work for me

Comment: I can't see *when* you are doing this and I suppose it's the problem.

Comment: How far from the bottom is it? a long way, or..

Comment: it's about in the middle of the screen

Comment: Do you have a DPI set other than default?

Comment: no, dpi are default

Comment: Do you get different results on ContentRendered ?

Comment: It works with ContentRendered. Maybe the errorr is that my Thread is running faster than the Thread who sets those values?

Comment: You are doing this in constructor, please do it instead in `Loaded` event as per answer in duplicate. Small details matter, never ignore them unless you have enough experience ;)

Comment: now I have it in the ContentRendered event, but it is still about 10px up

Comment: now it works but I am setting the window position in SetupWindow() and when ContentRendered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set the position when the ContentRendered is triggered. here the code:

```cs
private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Left = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width - Width - 2;
    Top = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height - Height - 2;
}
```